# Helm3 Kubernetes cluster unreachable - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: macos, openshift, helm3

After login to an OpenShift cluster, I'm trying to run `helm ls` and getting the following error:

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://<cluster-api-url>/version?timeout=32s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I tried to follow this post [helm: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119650/helm-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by always trusting the OpenShfit cluster.

1. I logged into the cluster throw the browser and found the certificate `issued by`
2. I chose to always trust this certificate: Keychain Access -> Certificates -> double-click on the certificate with the same `issue by` name -> Trust -> Always Trust

Answer (score 0):

Find cluster name

```bash
$ oc config get-clusters                                                                                              
NAME
api-example-com:6443
```

Disable cert checking

```bash
$ oc config set-cluster api-example-com --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
```